# Certificate revoked WM

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, windows-phone-8.1

I have problem. Since few days my app is generating

> System.Exception: The certificate is revoked. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80092010)

What is strange is that this is happening only on windows phone 8.1. On windows 10 mobile the same code works.

When inspecting certificate using

```
Information.ServerCertificate
```

I get information:

```
ValidFrom = {28.04.2016 12:16:06 +02:00}
ValidTo = {18.03.2019 07:28:26 +01:00}
```

This is how I start my socket connection:

```
 HostName host = address.RemoteHostName;
 string port = address.RemoteServiceName;

 CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
 cts.CancelAfter(6 * 1000);

 socket.ConnectAsync(host, port, SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12).AsTask(cts.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Should I do something in my app (can I debug or inspect it more thoroughly) or is it strictly connected with server certification?

EDIT:
4h later WM10 also started displaying revoked error while Android nad iOS has no problem connecting (windows for the past 1 year also had no problems). Is there a way to check if certificate really is revoked?

EDIT 2:
I added:

```
socket.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.RevocationInformationMissing);
socket.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.RevocationFailure);
```

So as It turns out windows has probles with obtaining revoked list. I will use this workournd for now but any help in solving this problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your phone date time settings?

Comment: @MikeHoltkamp date is correct, but if date was incorrect wouldn't it be expired exception?

Comment: You are rigtht I mixed up the expiration and revokation my bad